Clickhouse: Compare the performance of two queries using CTE
I have 2 queries as below:
Query1:
WITH (
    SELECT master_product_id 
    FROM product_report 
    WHERE 
        retailer_id = 1000
        AND (branch_id IN (1000))
        AND product_master_id = 1000
    LIMIT 1
    )
AS mpi
,variant AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.product_master_id
        ,p.master_product_id
        ,substr(p.product_name, LENGTH(p.product_original_name) + 3) AS product_name
    FROM product_report p
    WHERE 
        p.master_product_id = mpi
        AND retailer_id = 1000
        AND (branch_id IN (1000))
        AND p.is_deleted = 0
    )
SELECT * FROM variant --maybe other processing here

Query2:
WITH mpi
AS
    (
    SELECT master_product_id AS mi
    FROM product_report
    WHERE
        retailer_id = 1000
        AND (branch_id IN (1000))
        AND product_master_id = 1000
    LIMIT 1
    )
,variant
AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.product_master_id
        ,p.master_product_id
        ,substr(p.product_name, LENGTH(p.product_original_name) + 3) AS product_name
    FROM product_report p
        ,mpi
    WHERE
        mpi.mi = p.master_product_id
        AND retailer_id = 1000
        AND (branch_id IN (1000))
        AND p.is_deleted = 0
    )
SELECT * FROM variant --maybe other processing here

Method 1 I put mpi behind AS.
Method 2 I put mpi in front of AS.
In CTE mpi, I get the master id (which is unique) and use it as an input condition for the 2nd CTE. One more information, my product_report table has very large data, billions of records.
Are the two queries above different in terms of processing? Which sentence will have better performance?
Is there any way to optimize the above query?
Thanks for any advice!

In both queries, you are using CTE to perform a subquery, selecting a single master_product_id to be used in the second CTE. If master_product_id is unique, this operation is basically the same in both queries and should have similar performance. To compare performance, you can use 'EXPLAIN' command to see the query plan.
Regarding optimize the query, it is important to know how the source table product_report is created. It should be created in a way to match ow you usually query the data. Since you are querying based on retailer_id, branch_id, and product_master_id, these columns should be in the primary keys. And setting up data skipping indexes on these columns could also speed things up.
